# How to get all available information about a Person or other entity with SPARQL and DBPedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to be able to get information from the DBPedia's SPARQL endpoint by typing a name of a person and then retrieving all of the information available about this person or other entity.

For example I know I can use a query such as:

```
SELECT * {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle>
        dbo:birthYear ?birth;
        dbo:deathYear ?death;
        dbo:abstract ?comment.
    FILTER (lang(?comment)='en')
}
LIMIT 10
```

To get information about Aristotle's birth and death year as well as the information available in the abstract.

However, what I would want to achieve is to get all the available information for a person for each available attribute without specifying the each attributes.

Is this possible or should I just go to the ontology of the DBPedia and list all of the attributes available for a `Person` in the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variable predicates like this:

```
 SELECT ?p ?o {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle>
        ?p ?o . #?p is now a variable
   FILTER(LANG(?o) = 'en' || LANG(?o) = '' ||  !BOUND(LANG(?o)) )
}
```

Notice that when a language for the object `?o` is defined (a.k.a. 'bound') we return `?o` in English, or when `?o` is another literal (e.g. a number, and its language is bound to '', we return the literal.
Otherwise when there's no language, we just return `?o` (e.g. for IRIs, blanknodes, etc).

Comment: A question: Do you know why the the actual page in dbpedia has different information than the one provided by the query and is there a way to have more similar information to this available in the web page ?
https://dbpedia.org/page/Aristotle

Comment: Not sure. Do you have an example where there's a particular difference you don't want to see?

Comment: Ok I have identified the problem. By filtering and Bounding only to only 'en' a lot of information about other data types such as `areaTotal` `populationDensity` is not returned.

Comment: @ValerioCocchi your statement is not 100% correct or I misunderstand - it returns all bindings with either English or no language tag. Anything beyond would need usage of something like `coalesce` or multiple `OPTIONAL` patterns to apply preference

Comment: @UninformedUser I thought my method would return all the triples with Aristotle as subject, whilst avoiding repeating the same label in 50 languages.
However this seems to also not return numbers, though I would need to look into why this is.

Comment: it doesn't return numbers because it returns an empty string `""` for any literal without a language tag. `!bound()` only works for URIs and bnodes because there you have to apply `str` to make the function evaluate to something other than `false`